# Vaadin Hierarchical JPAContainer

Tags: java, vaadin

My class hierarchy consists of parent elements which have lists of child elements. Something like this:

```
public class ParentElement {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ChildElement> childs;
}
```

and

```
public class ChildElement {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

In the view for the ParentElement, I show the properties of the ParentElement (such as its name). For that, I create a JPAContainer and bind the properties to fields:

```
JPAContainer<ParentElement> parentElementContainer;
Filter filter = new Compare.Equal("id", id);
parentElementContainer = JPAContainerFactory.make(ParentElement.class, MyUI.PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
parentElementContainer.addContainerFilter(filter);
...
EntityItem<ParentElement> parentElementItem = parentElementContainer.getItem(id);
nameLabel.setPropertyDataSource(parentElementItem.getItemProperty("name"));
```

In the view for the ParentElement, I'd also like to show an editable grid containing a list of all its child elements. Ideally, I would do this:

```
childsGrid.setContainerDataSource(parentElementItem.getItemProperty("childs"));
```

But of course, this doesn't work because the item property is not a container itself. What's the best way to create a JPAContainer for the ParentElement's list of childs?

Comment: Not really an answer but have a look at Viritin which is a Vaadin extension and contains among many other things: `Lots of handy Field implementations e.g. for common relation types (@ManyToMany, @OneToMany, @ElementCollection in JPA terminology, but not tied to JPA)`. See https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/viritin